# Azure function to parse CSV from FTP to save it in Azure SQL DB

Tags: c#, ftp, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I need a function that reads csv files from FTP source and insert the file contents (including a new column containing the file name in the rows of the file ) into a specified table in Azure SQL DB

I managed to read the contents of the CSV file as a string, and was able to insert it in a table as a row for the whole strng. but I would like to know how can I parse the CSV string or read the csv file through the azure function as a table frame (for example). I noticed that the library for reading and parsing CSV  `Microsoft.VisualBasic.IO` is not available in the azure functions V.2 `.NET CORE` (was available in V.1 `.NET FRAMEWORK`  before)

```cs
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "System.Data"


using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using FluentFTP;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;






public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)

{
    using (FtpClient conn = new FtpClient()) 
        {
            conn.Host = "ftpLink";
            conn.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");

            //SQL connection
            var connectionstring = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqldb_connection");



            // get a list of files and directories in the "/OUT" folder
            foreach (FtpListItem item in conn.GetListing("/OUT")) 
                {

            // if this is a file and ends with CSV
                    if (
                    item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File
                    &&
                    item.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith(".csv")
                    )
                    {

                        //log.LogInformation(item.FullName);


                        var ftpUserName = "username";
                        var ftpPassword = "pass";
                        var filename = "/out/"+ item.Name;
                        string delimiter = ";";
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                        FtpWebRequest fileRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://link" + filename);
                        fileRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                        fileRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserName, ftpPassword);

                        WebClient client = new WebClient();
                        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserName, ftpPassword );




                        using (SqlConnection SQLcon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))

                        {
                            if (SQLcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                                SQLcon.Open();
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                                cmd.Connection = SQLcon;
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                SqlDataReader reader;
                            try
                                {
                                // that reads the file content as string
                                    byte[] newFileData = client.DownloadData("ftp://ftplink" + filename);
                                    string fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);

                                    string query = $"INSERT INTO [brt].[record] ([record_string]) VALUES ('{fileString}')";
                                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                                    log.LogInformation(fileString);
                                }

                            catch (WebException e)
                                {
                                    log.LogInformation(item.FullName);
                                } 

                        }   

                    }


                }
            return new OkObjectResult($"Hello");
        }
}
```

I need to dump the CSV contents into an SQL table filling its contents from the CSV, then with an extra column showing the CSV file name for each row of contents. The table to be something like the following:

```
column1          column2          column3          column4          filename

   2                4                5                a             file1.csv
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear how you are dumping the data into SQL. Is it (file name, all file data), (file name, file row), or (file name, individual data columns)? Could you also elaborate a bit on what you mean by "missing some values due to the space"? Does that mean the data is being truncated or that the data has issues because the csv is not being parsed correctly?

There are several 3rd party CSV parsers available for .Net Core: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/08/04/csv-parsing-in-net-core/

Comment: Pretty sure this would help you out: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: @Kev thank you for the library and the response. I will check the csv helper and see how to use it. I updated the question and at the end I put an example of how the table could be. The part of the missing values I have solved and it was my mistake while trying to parse it but it is not there anymore.

Comment: I would probably use Azure Data Factory for this rather than Azure Functions.  They have a default timeout of 5 mins which doesn’t necessarily tie in with a “for each” pattern and an INSERT into a db.  How many files are there?  How big are they?  What DTU are you running your db at?  These questions would be less of a concern for Data Factory IMHO.